# How to use the global definition of a variable in a command where that variable has already been defined?

Tags: highlighting, soul

I was trying to highlight some text, which contains `\x`, using the `\hl` command from the `soul` package, where `\x` is simply defined as `\def\x{\mathbf{x}}`.

However, I've found that `\x` has already been defined in `\hl`. As a result, the TeX compiler wrongly interprets `\hl{How to define $f(\x_i)$?}`, where `\x` actually takes as the value `define`.

Can I know how to enforce the global definition of `\x` inside `\hl`? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\def\x{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

How to define $\x$?

\hl{How to define $\x$?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\x{\mathbf{x}}` will bite you in the end ... or more precisely now, because you get into troubles...

Comment: Exactly which error do you get? Using my TexLive 2019, I get no errors with your example. Note: I agree with Christian: a normal user should never use `\def`

Comment: On a simpler note why dont you change the `\x` definition in your document?

Comment: @daleif There is no error, but the output is not as expected. It shows 'How to define $define$' and not 'How to define $\mathbf{x}$'

Comment: I guess you can't really do a lot here other than using a command name different from `\x`. `soul` uses `\x` internally all over the place and does not check if it is already defined.

Comment: well it is imho a rather bad idea from soul to use \x as a scratch command, but there is not much you can do beside complaining to the maintainer. So don't use \x yourself.

Comment: @daleif: Actually I did not refer to the `\def` (but I agree with you), but rather frown on those laziness shortcuts such as `\x` etc..

Comment: @ChristianHupfer there I also agree

Comment: @moewe right, never checked the output as the OP mentioned getting an errror. I did not.

Comment: @daleif @Christian Hupfer, thanks for the reply. I used the shortcut `\x` mainly for brevity and my personal habit for writing bold-face x in math mode. And I accidentally discovered the above issue, so tried to summarize it as a common one. Just wondering if there is any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very unfortunate that the author of `soul` misunderstood the usage of `\x`, which should be

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup<material>}\x
```

instead of

```
\edef\x{<material>}\x
```

The former only redefines `\x` in a group and a possible definition of `\x` is irrelevant; when the redefined `\x` is executed, the group ends and the redefinition vanishes.

You can cure the disease by changing `\x` into a different scratch macro, here I used `\SOUL@x`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@flushcomma}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@flushapo}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@flushgrave}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@addgroup}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@addmath}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@addprotect}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@addtoken}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\soulregister}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@doword}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@dosyllable}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@gettoken}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@puttoken}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@nexttoken}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\SOUL@soeverytoken}{\x}{\SOUL@x}{}{}
\makeatother


\newcommand\x{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

How to define $\x$?

\hl{How to define $\x$?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`soul` uses the name `\x` internally as a scratch command to temporarily store stuff all over the place. (Just search for `\x` or `\edef\x` in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.dtx.) The way the package is written there is little to no chance to get it to stop doing that easily (short of replacing every occurence of `\x` in the source with `\soul@tempa` or trying to patch the package to the same effect), so I guess you should

1. Complain to the author of `soul` and suggest he use an 'internal' name as scratch command.
2. Use a macro name other than `\x` for your `\textbf{x}`. Make it semantic. You could for example say

   ```
   \newcommand*{\vector}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
   ```

   and then use `\vector{x}` or if you want one command

   ```
   \newcommand*{\vector}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
   \newcommand*{\vecx}{\vector{x}}
   ```

   and use `\vecx`.

It is usually safer to steer clear of one-letter commands. Even though they are very handy (at least superficially) many are already taken and redefining those could lead to catastrophic consequences.

It wouldn't have helped here, but it could help in other cases and is therefore a good practice in LaTeX documents to use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`. `\def` just overwrites an existing command, while `\newcommand` will throw an error if you try to do that. That helps avoid some of the more common 'you defined an important macro that is used all over the place' issues.